# Console application in .NET incorporating QGIS tools

Tags: qgis, .net

I am working on a project where I want to build a standalone application in .NET using QGIS tools. Is there any option like the ArcObjects SDK for .NET? Please help me on this.

Answer (score 2):

No there is no .NET libraries for QGIS.  The only options there are Python and C++.